# Рандомное изменения

Tags: php, mysql

Например, у нас есть три записи в таблице users , в каждой записи есть столбик har. Вопрос каким запросом изменить каждой записи har рандомно, например первая запись будет иметь har=1 вторая запись будет иметь har=2 а третья будет иметь har=3 спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заполнить значениями от 7 до 12

```
update table set har=floor(7 + (rand() * 5))
```

принцип действия следующий: floor(start+(rand()*(end-start))